# Sql Server Cast & Convert DateTime and DateTime2 Fail Relentlessly

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime

Firstly, Here is some information about my environment:

I'm running a SQL 2005 database on a SQL 2014 instance. COLLATION is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. Here are the results of my DBCC USEROPTIONS

- textsize  2147483647
- language  us_english
- dateformat    mdy
- datefirst 7
- lock_timeout  -1
- quoted_identifier SET
- arithabort    SET
- ansi_null_dflt_on SET
- ansi_warnings SET
- ansi_padding  SET
- ansi_nulls    SET
- concat_null_yields_null   SET
- isolation level   read committed

Here is my problem.

I keep running into the following 2 errors depending on when I try to select from a view and us a WHERE clause against a converted column of type DATETIME or DATETIME2.

(DATETIME2)
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 122
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

And...

(DATETIME)
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 122
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

My problem SOUNDS deceptively simple, like I must be a mook and am either passing in an incorrectly formatted value in the WHERE or not taking into account the language settings, collation, and optimizer precedence.

So here is my query.

```
DECLARE @DATEVALUE DATETIME = '01-05-2015 14:23:05'
SELECT t.* FROM Reports.MyReportView WHERE t.MyDateColumn = @DATEVALUE
```

This fails MISERABLY no matter what I try.

I have no problem casting and converting character strings to DATETIME. 
Like...

```
SELECT CAST('03/28/2011 18:03:40' AS DATETIME)
```

Works just fine.

The problem only seems to happen in my WHERE clause. I've looked at tons of suggestions, tried lots of things such as changing the language settings to british or french, changing the DATEFORMAT to ymd, dmy, mdy, tried some other solutions I found such as...

```
DECLARE @F7 nvarchar(10) = '01/05/2015'
DECLARE @F8 nvarchar(10) = '00:00:00'
DECLARE @NEWTIME DATETIME

DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(20)
SET @Date = RIGHT(@F7,4)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@F7,4,2)+'/'+LEFT(@F7,2)

DECLARE @time DATETIME
SET @time =  CONVERT(DATETIME, @Date + ' ' + @F8)
```

...And yes, that outputs a DATETIME just fine. But the moment I try to use the value in my WHERE clause ... KAAAABOOOOOOOM!!! So I've had no luck resolving this problem.

The only thing I can think of is that the optimizer is punking me because it's rearranging the query behind the scenes and I am comparing a VALID datetime variable to an invalid VARCHAR string PRIOR to when I am converting the string in the query order, and so it is the View that is actually causing the failure and has nothing to do with SQL Server's datetime conversions.

Please help.

**UPDATE**

Ok Fixed. I followed advice from everyone and rewrote the date conversion in the View into a SubQuery/SubView and then Joined it. Here is what the new conversion code looks like...

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,
CASE 
    WHEN   
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN REPLACE(ISNULL(t.DayCol,''),' ','') = '' 
            THEN NULL ELSE REPLACE(ISNULL(t.DayCol,''),' ','') END
    ) IS NULL
    OR 
        (
            CASE WHEN REPLACE(ISNULL(t.MonthCol,''),' ','') = '' 
            THEN NULL ELSE REPLACE(ISNULL(t.MonthCol,''),' ','') END
        ) IS NULL
    OR 
        (
            CASE WHEN REPLACE(ISNULL(t.YearCol,''),' ','') = '' 
            OR t.YearCol = 'NoSelection' 
            THEN NULL ELSE t.YearCol END
        ) IS NULL
    OR  
    ISDATE
    (
        CONCAT
            (
                RIGHT('0' +REPLACE(MonthCol,' ',''),2),'/',
                RIGHT('0' + REPLACE(t.DayCol,' ',''), 2),'/',
                REPLACE(YearCol,' ','')
            )
    ) = 0
    THEN NULL
    ELSE 
    CONCAT
    (
        RIGHT('0' +REPLACE(MonthCol,' ',''),2),'/',
        RIGHT('0' + REPLACE(t.MonthCol,' ',''), 2),'/',
        REPLACE(YearCol,' ','')
    )
END) as 'MyDateColumn'
```

This is embarassing code, but it works, solves the problem and is unfortunately necessary because somebody didn't want to store date values as date columns in a wacky database structure... so maybe it will help somebody who runs into this problem.

Comment: "This fails MISERABLY", "KABOOOM"....can you tell us what actually happens?

Comment: One thing that I will recommend is using ISO 8601 Date Formats (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`) in your code.  This will eliminate localization from affecting things.  Then if you are using ISO dates and get an error it can be easy to track down.  As to the failures, the code of the View would be helpful here.

Comment: How are you populating the date column in the view?

Comment: Also you may get more useful help on DBA.Stackexchange  Most of those guys are great at TSQL (I used to be one in my old job)

Comment: @Lamak - Reread, the error messages are listed.

Comment: @WindRaven - Formatting options are for converting FROM DateTime TO Varchar only. SQL Server always recognizes ONE Datetime format. Also using the #DATE variable of type DATETIME would eliminate the issue in most circumstances which is what leads me to believe it's a problem with the View.

Comment: @ChrisCampbell  Server Localization options determine how the string 1/12/2014 converts to date time, Is it Jan 12, 2014 or DEC 1, 2014 (depends on the nation).  the ISO 2014-01-12 is ALWAYS Jan 12, 2014 no matter what the server localization settings are.  That is what I was referencing and not the CONVERT syntax.

Comment: @WindRaven my misunderstanding sorry. Yes, I have tried changing the locaization settings, again this is why I'm thinking it's the view and the optimizer is punking me.

Comment: @ChrisCampbell  Can you post the code for the view?  That would point out what is going on.  Its not the optimizer doing any thing to you since its a data type issue.  The code for the View will be the key to solving this.  (Since the view could be doing something funky like returning a char data type and not a datetime like you are expecting and its on the View getting implicitly converted to a date time and exploding)

Comment: Ok, figured it out following David P's suggestion. The Optimizer punked me, it was the View, the conversion was happening in the top level query, so when the Optimizer decided it knew best... boom. The problem was my fault ( of course) because when building that automagical date column I was not cleaning the other columns I was consolidating correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data column that you are converting from can contain nulls or possibly have invalid date data in it, then you are going to get this error. The SQL engine will try to do the CAST on all the potential data BEFORE it filters the data on the WHERE clause. What you need to do is do a subquery, and then select and cast against that:

```
SELECT CAST(a.StringField AS datetime) AS TheDate
FROM (
    SELECT a.* FROM MyTable WHERE StringField = '12/1/2014'
) a
```

OR:

```
SELECT CAST(a.StringField AS datetime) AS TheDate
FROM (
    SELECT a.* FROM MyTable WHERE ISDATE(StringField) = 1
) a
WHERE CAST(a.StringField as datetime) = '12/1/2014'
```

Comment: I will try to reorganize the query into a subquery and see what happens. I still think the optimizer may decide it knows best again if it does succeed but something is better than nothing at this point. Maybe instead of a view I should use a SPROC and change the architecture a bit.

Comment: Yes ... Optimizer pwned me Hard. I rewrote the Query, cleanly removed any values that showed as ISDATE(...) = 0 and moved my conversions into a SubView (because it was a rather complex operation to create a date values from poorly poorly formatted tables to begin with). After that, referenced the Sub-View and now equality operations are performing beautifully. ARRRRRRRG BEWARE THE OPTIMIZER! It is smarter than me :(